# How do I convert Eastings and Northings projection to WSG84 in geopandas?

Tags: wgs84, geopandas

I'm very new to projections and struggling to convert a map dataset from OSGB36 (Eastings and Northings) to WGS84 (lat/longs).

I've used geopandas to import a shapefile. Now I want to export it as GeoJSON so I can then use Folium to map it on leaflet.js.

If I check the crs variable with .crs I get:

```
{u'datum': u'OSGB36',
u'k': 0.999601272,
u'lat_0': 49,
u'lon_0': -2,
u'no_defs': True,
u'proj': u'tmerc',
u'units': u'm',
u'x_0': 400000,
u'y_0': -100000}
```

Trouble is if I'm a bit lost on the attributes to set to convert it to WGS84:

```
staffs.to_crs({'datum':"wgs84"})

RuntimeError: projection not named
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
staffs.to_crs(epsg=4326)
```

Comment: Oh. One problem. The conversion seems to have mapped northings and eastings to the wrong corresponding figure. I guess that's part of the dataset I was given. Don't suppose there's a simple transform? (No problems, if not).

Comment: Do you mean northings and eastings are reversed?

Comment: Yes. I'm very new with this geo stuff.

Comment: Actually, that's not true. I've just imported it into Folium and now the map displays beautifully.

Comment: I don't know the source of your specific problem, but it's a common problem for beginners to reverse coordinate orders since in we generally say (latitude, longitude) and (northing, easting), but most mapping software uses cartesian ordering (x,y) and is therefore in a different order.