# What units are used by GeoPandas/Shapely area and distance functions?

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas

it looks like a silly question, yet I can't find clear answer on that:
what units geopandas/shapely use calculating distance/area between objects?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html) uses a cartesian plane system for computing geometries (distance = euclidean distance)

> Shapely does not support coordinate system transformations. All operations on two or more features presume that the features exist in the same Cartesian plane.

[GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) uses [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) to read shapefiles (and others) and [Pyproj](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj) for cartographic transformations.

> The coordinate reference system (CRS) of the collection’s vector data is accessed via a read-only crs attribute.

```py
import fiona
c = fiona.open("test.shp")
print c.crs['units']
m
```

The unit for calculating distance/area between objects with Shapely is meter in this case.

It is the same with GeoPandas

```py
import geopandas as gp
df = gp.GeoDataFrame.from_file('test.shp')
print df.crs['units']
m
```

That means that if you work with a crs.unit = degree (WGS84 for example) all calculations are wrong.You must first reproject you layer ([How do I convert Eastings and Northings projection to WSG84 in geopandas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91135/how-do-i-convert-eastings-and-northings-projection-to-wsg84-in-geopandas/91139?noredirect=1#91139)
)

Comment: Does anything change when you load from PostGIS instead? I am setting the coordinates as an argument when calling `read_postgis` the resulting data frame only has attribute `crs`, which is a string. It does not have attribute `crs['units']`; attempting to request that results in a TypeError.

Comment: For 2020, in Geopandas you must use df.crs.axis_info[0].unit_name  to get the units that are being used.

Comment: @gene Would you be able to update your answer to include using `df.crs.axis_info[0].unit_name` from the comments? `df.crs['units']` must be obsolete now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Whichever units are represented by the coordinates in your geometries.

Shapely geometries are Cartesian and make no assumptions about being Lon/Lat or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

For Geopandas, it depends of the assigned Coordinate Reference System to the GeoDataFrame.

For shapely its in the same units of the cartesian plane, shapely does not support CRS [source](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#coordinate-systems).