# Understanding the working of buffer in shapely

Tags: shapely

I have a linestring which I need to buffer but the problem is that I am not able to understand the unit metric in which the buffer function accepts the linestring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [geopandas/shapely: what units it uses/calculates for area and distance functions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166675/geopandas-shapely-what-units-it-uses-calculates-for-area-and-distance-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Shapely's [project page](http://toblerity.org/shapely/project.html):

> Shapely is not concerned with data formats or coordinate systems, but
>   can be readily integrated with packages that are.

so @Jon's answer is correct. The unit depends on the unit of your input data. You can use geopandas, pyproj or GDAL to convert your lineString to another crs.

Answer (score 0):

If the coordinates are in degrees, I believe the buffer unit will be as well. If you want to specify meters or feet, you need to first reproject your geometry into a CRS that uses meters or feet.