# Using Shapely's ops.snap?

Tags: shapely, linestring, snapping

I have two polylines whose endpoints are near to each other, but do not overlap. I've put them into [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PlKRuFfGBQyCf4G452CETaKktiKKmJfP) shapefile. I want to use shapely's ops.snap() to snap their endpoints, but it's not working as expected.

```
from shapely import ops
import geopandas as gpd

wontsnap = gpd.read_file(path_to_wontsnap)
g1 = wontsnap.geometry.values[0]
g2 = wontsnap.geometry.values[1]
```

If I check the distance between the geometries, I get

```
g1.distance(g2)
Out[661]: 0.0006421029901831172
```

This agrees (roughly) with the measure tool in QGIS:

[image]

Now if I try to snap the two geometries with a tolerance that is greater than the distance between their endpoints:

```
snapped = ops.snap(g1, g2, 0.001)
```

The `snapped` object contains only the `g1` geometry. I.e., they don't snap.

If I increase the tolerance by 10x:

```
snapped = ops.snap(g1, g2, 0.01)
```

The `snapped` object includes both geometries, snapped correctly.

If I trim the `g1` and `g2` geometries to the last and first 10 points, respectively, snapping works as expected.

I have tried various tolerances between 0.001 and 0.01--the geometries will snap at 0.003 but not 0.002. At this point I can only assume this is a bug in shapely--any ideas?

---

I have posted this as a [bug report](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/646) in the shapely repository. It appears to be a bug.

Comment: please provide a short WKT that demonstrates the issue

Comment: The projection of your shapefile is WGS84 and the coordinates are in longitude, latitude (angles in degrees). Shapely uses a cartesian plane system for computing geometries (distance = euclidean distance). That means that all your distance calculations are wrong without reprojecting your layer ([What units are used by GeoPandas/Shapely area and distance functions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/166684/2581))

Comment: @Gene, then why does shapely's distance() function return the correct distance? Shapely doesn't care about your projection, and euclidean distance between lat/lon is fine with me. I'm not trying to compute a meaningful distance, I'm trying to snap points that are within a threshold distance. Cartesian is fine.

Comment: @Ian, I can't do it, that's why I uploaded the shapefile. Like I said, when I try to snip the polylines down to 10 points, the snapping works fine. So I can't provide a shortened version of the polylines, which are hundreds of points. I can paste in a wkt of the entire thing if you want, but they're already provided as a shapefile so I'm not inclined to do that.

Comment: "and euclidean distance between lat/lon is fine  with me": Did you realize what you're writing ?

Comment: Indeed, I do. It is not a distance that is meaningful in terms of length. If it makes it easier for people to understand my question, pretend that the points aren't lon/lat, but just x,y coordinates on a plane. I intentionally left out that they were coordinates because it's irrelevant to the problem I'm asking about.

Comment: If the issue goes away when you reduce the number of points it is probably a validity issue not a bug.

Comment: @Ian, well, remember that the snapping *does* work, but only when the tolerance is well beyond what should be required. Additionally, is_valid returns True for both g1 and g2.