# Calculating distance between 2 Shapely Points in Meters

Tags: python, postgis, shapely, geoalchemy-2, sqlalchemy

I am trying to calculate the distance (in meters) between 2 lon/lng points of type `shapely.geometry.point.Point` using Python and Shapely. These 2 points are returned from PostGIS by SQLAlchemy/Geoalchemy2 as `geoalchemy2.elements.WKBElement`, which is then converted to shapely's `shapely.geometry.point.Point` using geoalchemy2.

However, when I try to use the `distance` function to calculate the distance in meters, the result is expected to be around 1490 m, but the code calculated it to be 0.013402616901217364.

What went wrong with our code?

*Note: Distance calculations will not exceed 30 km*

```py
from geoalchemy2.shape import to_shape

users = db_session().query(User).limit(2).all()
foo, bar = users[0], users[1]

print(type(foo.coordinates))               # <class 'geoalchemy2.elements.WKBElement'>
print(type(to_shape(foo.coordinates)))     # <class 'shapely.geometry.point.Point'>

distance = to_shape(foo.coordinates).distance(to_shape(bar.coordinates))
print(distance)                            # 0.013402616901217364
```

Comment: Look at [What units are used by GeoPandas/Shapely area and distance functions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/166684/2581)

Comment: @gene Thanks, if I understand it correctly it appears that Shapely calculates the Euclidean distance, which is does not suitable for lat/lng data which requires WGS84 distance for it to be in the unit of meters. In this case, is it easier/better to work with the `WKBElement` originally returned by Geoalchemy?

Comment: Simply change the projection of the geometry

Comment: @Nyxynyx, You're right about shapely returning the euclidean distance. If you want to do operations that involve CRS information, you'll probably want to use either `geopandas` or `pyproj` (which is what geopandas uses). For example [`pyproj.Geod.inv`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.inv) will solve your problem, I think.